# Replace values in a dictionary with values from another dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an English dictionary and I am trying to replace values in the English dictionary to make it a Spanish dictionary using the translatedTerms. Can someone please guide me through this?

```
var englishDict = {
  "name": "Please enter your name",
  "list": ["translate", "object", "made"],
  "nested": {
    "hello": "hello",
    "world": "world"
    }
};


var translatedTerms = {
  "Please enter your name" : "Por favor, escriba su nombre",
  "translate" : "traducir",
  "object" :"objeto",
  "made" : "hecho",
  "hello" : "hola",
  "world": "mundo"
}
```

**My desired Output**

```
var spanishDict = {
      "name": "Por favor, escriba su nombre",
      "list": ["traducir", "objeto", "hecho"],
      "nested": {
        "hello": "hola",
        "world": "mundo"
        }
    };
```

Comment: What part are you stuck with?

Comment: Your translatedTerms object only supports 2 languages. IMHO better to store each dictionary including all translations separate and independent.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var englishDict = {
    "name": "Please enter your name",
    "list": ["translate", "object", "made"],
    "nested": {
        "hello": "hello",
        "world": "world"
    }
};


var translatedTerms = {
    "Please enter your name" : "Por favor, escriba su nombre",
    "translate" : "traducir",
    "object" :"objeto",
    "made" : "hecho",
    "hello" : "hola",
    "world": "mundo"
}

var spanishDict = {}

var key,value,newObject;
for(key in englishDict){
    value = englishDict[key];
    if(typeof value ==='string'){ // If it's a string
        if(value in translatedTerms)
            spanishDict[key] = translatedTerms[value]; // Replace from translatedTerms
        else
            spanishDict[key] = value; // If not found in translatedTerms, keep original
    }
    else if(Array.isArray(value)){ // If it's an array
        spanishDict[key] = value.map((item)=>{
            if(item in translatedTerms) // Replace from translatedTerms
                return translatedTerms[item];
            return item; // If not found in translatedTerms, keep original
        })
    }
    else if(typeof value === 'object' && value !== null){ // If it's an object and not null
        newObject = {};
        Object.keys(value).map((_key)=>{
            if(_key in translatedTerms)
                newObject[_key] = translatedTerms[_key]; // Replace from translatedTerms
            else
                newObject[_key] = value[_key]; // If not found in translatedTerms, keep original
        })
        spanishDict[key] = newObject;
    }
}
console.log(spanishDict)
```

---

Output

```js
{ name: 'Por favor, escriba su nombre',
  list: [ 'traducir', 'objeto', 'hecho' ],
  nested: { hello: 'hola', world: 'mundo' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

This `translate()` function iterates the dictionary recursively, and if the current `dict` is:

1. an array - maps the array, and calls `translate()` on each item.
2. an object - converts the object to entries, maps the entries, and calls `translate()` on the value of each entry. The entries are then converted back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.
3. other - returns the value of the item from the `terms` object, or returns the item itself if it doesn't exist on the `terms` object.

You need to handle four cases:

1. `dict` is an array

```js
const translate = (dict, terms) => {
  if(Array.isArray(dict)) { // if it's an array map it
    return dict.map(t => translate(t, terms));
  }
  
  if(typeof dict === 'object' && dict !== null) {
    return Object.fromEntries( // if it's an object map the entries, and convert them back to object
      Object.entries(dict)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, translate(v, terms)]
      )
    );
  }
  
  return dict in terms ? terms[dict] : dict; // translate if exists as a key on terms, and return if not
};

const englishDict = {"name":"Please enter your name","list":["translate","object","made"],"nested":{"hello":"hello","world":"world"}};

const translatedTerms = {"Please enter your name":"Por favor, escriba su nombre","translate":"traducir","object":"objeto","made":"hecho","hello":"hola","world":"mundo"};

const result = translate(englishDict, translatedTerms);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern (ECMAScript 2019), pure, non-mutable, functional solution:

```
const englishDict = {
  "name": "Please enter your name",
  "list": ["translate", "object", "made"],
  "nested": {
    "hello": "hello",
    "world": "world"
    }
}

const translatedTerms = {
  "Please enter your name" : "Por favor, escriba su nombre",
  "translate" : "traducir",
  "object" :"objeto",
  "made" : "hecho",
  "hello" : "hola",
  "world": "mundo"
}

const translateObject = obj => {
  const translatedEntries = Object
     .entries(obj)
     .map(([key, value]) => ([key, translate(value)]))

  return Object.fromEntries(translatedEntries)
}

const translate = el => {
  if (typeof el === 'string') {
    return translatedTerms[el]
  }

  if (Array.isArray(el)) {
    return el.map(word => translatedTerms[word])
  }

  if (typeof el === 'object' && el !== null) {
    return translateObject(el)
  }

  return el
}
// solution:
translateObject(englishDict)
```